# how do I retrieve my photos that are stored for the last five years while I was with iPhone now that I'm using Android

Tags: icloud, android

I was with iPhone for over 5 years and stored all of my photos in iCloud now that I have switched to an Android mobile I have lost access to my iPhone pictures is there any way for me to retrieve my photos from the iCloud so that I can view them on my Android? And I need to be able to do this without using a PC because I do not have access to one.

Comment: Can you access https://www.icloud.com/ from within the browser on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

### Download photos from iCloud using a smartphone

Assuming you have not the possibility to access a Computer, and the only way of browsing the Internet is using your phone running Android, you may want to follow these few steps:

1. **Open** your Internet browser, and visit the [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/) website.
2. **Sign in** with your **AppleID** (the one you used in your previous iPhone)
3. **Tap** the **Photos** App in the Home screen that will appear
4. **Select** the photos left in your iCloud Photo Library and then **tap** on **download**